# THREE Canvas texture not mapping to entire SphereMesh

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, three.js, html5-canvas

I'm working with THREE.js and I recently attempted to use a `<canvas>` element as a `THREE.Texture`. I've been able to map the object to the mesh successfully (finally!) but I've noticed that the texture is behaving a little oddly. Unfortunately the texture is only sitting on the bottom of my `SphereGeometry` instead of wrapping around it.

This is my implementation:

```
config = config || {} // setting up obj for return

config.canvas = config.canvas || document.createElement("canvas");
config.context. = config.canvas.getContext("2d");
config.context.font = "Bold 40px Arial";
config.context.fillStyle =  "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)";
config.context.fillText("Hello Stack", 0, 50);

config.texture = new THREE.Texture(config.canvas); // my sphere texture
config.texture.needsUpdate = true;
config.texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
config.texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter; 
config.texture.format = THREE.RGBFormat;


config.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 100, 40), 
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffaa00, map: config.texture}));

config.mesh.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(-1, 1, 1));       

return config.mesh;
```

Edit: #1 I thought I should note that the canvas element that I'm trying to use is dynamically generated. It comes as a base `<canvas>` element that doesn't have a `width` or `height` assigned. 
Edit: #2 I got a data URI from the element itself. It seems the `<canvas>` unit is rendering the images really small; which is probably part of the problem. Not sure how to compensate for that. I tried doing some width/height manipulation on the DoM element. Didn't work initially, will keep trying.

Comment: I think, the texture will be draw on each segment. You have 100 width- and 40 height-segments. Try to reduce them like `new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 3, 2)` or use the defaults `new THREE.SphereGeometry(100 /* , 8, 6 */)`

Comment: I'm using the `<canvas>` element to wrap to a inverted `sphereGeometry`. Can I resize the mesh after I have declared it with the same level of redrawining?

Answer (score 0):

I have been experimenting with this, and what I noticed is that when I didn't try and resize the `<canvas>` element the texture map actually was fine. Really unusual; so in the event where you can't seem to correct the issue manually, let the THREE.js engine map the texture itself.